# How to select HtmlElement in WebBrowser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I`m having a webBrowser control with some span elements.

Now user clicks on one of them, I do some manipulations and after that I need to select clicked element in browser. How can I do this?

```
HtmlElement hitElement = exerciseTextEditorControl.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition);
if (lastHitElement == null)
    return;
// Some stuff elided
// Now need to make a selection of this element in web browser
```

I know I can use IHTMLTxtRange for selecting some text, but how can I do similar thing with HtmllElement?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer. In case someone needs this as well:

```
public void SetSelectedElement(HtmlElement element)
    {
        IHTMLSelectionObject selection = HtmlDocument2.selection;

        var htmlTxtRange = selection.createRange() as IHTMLTxtRange;
        var iHtml = element.DomElement as IHTMLElement;
        htmlTxtRange.moveToElementText(iHtml);
        htmlTxtRange.select();
    }
```